# Function call parameter type mismatch with URL type

Tags: ios, swift

I have recently started programming in Swift 4 and have a compile error to resolve. I have an @IBACTION function called playVideo which plays a video but I want to be able to capture frames from the video as well for further processing.  This @IBAction function is shown below:

```
@IBAction func playVideo (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.present(self.playerController, animated:true, completion: {
        self.playerController.player?.play()
        var grabTime = 1.22  
        generateThumbnail(url: URL, fromTime: Float64(grabTime))
    })
}
```

The function playVideo which calls (generateThumbnail) is provided below. When I attempt to compile the program it fails with the function call "generateThumbnail(url:URL, fromTime: Float64(grabTime))" in playVideo with the error:

> "cannot convert value of type 'URL.Type' to expected argument type 'URL'

Can anyone help to resolve this issue? I have looked on this site for other errors of this type but they don't seem to cover these particular circumstances which is why I raised this now.

```
func generateThumbnail(url: URL, fromTime:Float64) -> UIImage? {
    let asset :AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
    assetImgGenerate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
    let time        : CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, 600)
    var img: CGImage?
    do {
        img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at:time, actualTime: nil)
    } catch {
    }
    if img != nil {
        let frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: img!)
        return frameImg
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing `URL`, which is a type, to `generateThumbnail`, you need to pass the actual url of your asset

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    generateThumbnail(url: URL, fromTime: Float64(grabTime))
```

To

```
    generateThumbnail(url: url, fromTime: Float64(grabTime))
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but it does not work. I am now getting a run-time error 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: It does work. it fixes your compile error doesn't it? What you are seeing is a different error.

Comment: thanks got it working and you were right. I had some other issues with the code which i sorted. thanks